# ttyAMA0 serial port error

Tags: pi-2, serial

I'm trying to get gps data through ttyAMA0 serial port.
Sometimes I could get gps data but I also get errors such as OSError Error11 resource unavailability.

It used to be working but I get errors after I changed the serial configuration through sudo raspi-config. It seems ttyAMA0 serial port is sometimes used by other process but I'm not sure which process is responsible for it.

Is there any way I could check this situation and solve this error by making ttyAMA0 serial port is only used by gps module?

My pi is rapsberry pi 2 and OS is Rasbian version 8 (Jessie).

Thank you

Comment: Rasbian(sic) version 8 (Jessie) is **OBSOLETE** and has been for 8 years. Without detail (code & connections) this is unanswerable. It is unlikely anyone on this site is using it.

Answer (score 0):

Go into raspi-config and undo the serial configuration you changed.

It sounds like you enabled a serial console.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]